# Create RobotFramework Keyword in Python for ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm trying to create a keyword that can get URL during my testcase from the chromedriver.

I want do this because in a specific page i need to be logged and i cannot just do a lxml that get url.

So how can i create a keyword that interact with the current page in the chromedriver ?

Here is the beginning of a keyword I defined:

```
def Count_Element_In_WebPage(Searched_Text):
    
    page = [CURRENT_PAGE]
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    
    [THE REST OF MY CODE]
    .
    .
    .
```

How can I do ?

Thanks a lot before your answers ! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to clarify what your end goal is; as written, the question contradicts itself. The title is - how to get the active webdriver (easy, one answer); the first sentence is how to get the current url (easy, another answer); but then there's lxml (xml parsing lib) and a code for counting the number of nodes in html (easy-ish, a third answer). Clarification is a must - and one or the questions.

Comment: I need help to create a Keyword in python (no robotframework langage) for manipulate élément in page, but i dont know how make work the keyword on the browser that is open for the test. How connect my keyword to the testing browser ?